Rspec Command Not Being Recognized?
I installed Rspec with gem install rspec but Rspec was apparently not being recognized. I'm not sure why.
I've been trying to get rpsec to work for the past couple of days. I'm not using a bundle. I'm just typing in gem install rspec in my powershell. I also made sure that my environment variables has the path to the ruby bin folder. I'm not really sure what my options are at this point. I uninstalled and reinstalled rspec as well but to no avail.
PS C:\Users\User> gem install rspec
Fetching rspec-3.13.0.gem
Successfully installed rspec-3.13.0
Parsing documentation for rspec-3.13.0
Installing ri documentation for rspec-3.13.0
Done installing documentation for rspec after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
PS C:\Users\User> gem list rspec

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rspec (3.13.0)
rspec-core (3.13.0)
rspec-expectations (3.13.2)
rspec-mocks (3.13.1)
rspec-support (3.13.1)
PS C:\Users\User> rspec
rspec : The term 'rspec' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ rspec
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (rspec:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

